# getAttribute printing in console but causing errors

Tags: javascript, xml, tags, titanium, getattribute

I'm parsing an xml feed and it seems to be working fine. I am encountering a problem when trying to extract an attribute from within a tag.

I am using Titanium and getting an error to debug on the line where I declare str3, **HOWEVER**, the console **IS** printing the correct data??

How could this be? Code below:

```
var str3=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure").item(0).getAttribute("url");

console.log("MP3 TEST 2-------------"+str3);
```

I tried to include a test for if (str3 is null) but I'm still getting the error when trying to test for it. Help appreciated!

Comment: replace `.item(0)` with `[0]`

Comment: We need more sauce. What is the error showing up? Give us more code.

Comment: @Jeff Noel Thats the annoying thing. I am not getting any specific error, the line is just highlighted blue with an arrow saying to debug current instruction pointer

Comment: @adeneo I'm trying that now, I tried it yesterday though, I think, and to no avail. I think .item(0) is how Titanium does it

Comment: @adeneo Yep still getting the blue highlighted error! Your way is not printing the correct data to the console

Comment: maybe you can show the XML you are trying to parse?

Comment: @AaronSaunders It's www.highlandradio.com/feed and FYI items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text in the same loop and it's working fine. I'm doing the same with a good few tags but the error is occuring when I'm trying to get a specific attribute. Even though it's printing in the console

Answer (score 0):

```
var str3=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure")[0].getAttribute("url");
```

Comment: That is what adeneo suggested already, but that is not working. I've just realised it doesn't even print the correct data to the console